# Return a value from lambda function inside a function c++

Tags: c++, lambda, rabbitmq

I am working with RabbiMQ (RPC) and I want to return a value from a lambda function. I am calling this function from main.cpp but the return value is not as expected (the value inside the lambda function is as expected). What is the right syntax for this?

My code:

```
bool RabbitMqHandler::sendResultToUserCountService(analyze_result result, Camera *cam)
{
    std:: string queueName = "userCountServiceReceiveRPC" + std::to_string(cam->getUserGroupId());

    const std::string correlation("2");

    SimplePocoHandler handler("localhost", 5672);

    AMQP::Connection connection(&handler, 
                                AMQP::Login("localhost","123456!"),"/");

    bool isExist;
    AMQP::Channel channel(&connection);
    AMQP::QueueCallback callback = [&](const std::string &name,
                                       int msgcount,
                                       int consumercount)
    {

         ProtobufLPR::CarResult carResult;

         carResult.set_licensenumber(result.LicenseNumber);
         carResult.set_analyzetime(result.Date);

         std::string buf;
         carResult.SerializeToString(&buf);

         AMQP::Envelope env(buf);
         env.setCorrelationID(correlation);
         env.setReplyTo(name);
         channel.publish("", queueName, env);
         std::cout << "Requesting " << result.LicenseNumber << std::endl;
    };

    channel.declareQueue(AMQP::exclusive).onSuccess(callback);

    auto receiveCallback = [&](const AMQP::Message &message,
                               uint64_t deliveryTag,
                               bool redelivered) ->bool
    {
        if(message.correlationID() != correlation)
            return 1;

        std::cout<<"Got " << message.message() <<std::endl;
        handler.quit();
        istringstream(message.message()) >> isExist;
        return isExist;
      };

      channel.consume("", AMQP::noack).onReceived(receiveCallback);
      handler.loop();
}
```

Comment: The syntax to return something from a lambda is `return ...;` just like you're doing. Please try and create a [mcve]. There is no way of knowing what the problem is with this limited information.

Comment: Presumably you want to make `sendResultToUserCountService` return from within the lambda there. The easiest way is probably to declare a `bool ret = false;` in the outer function, modify it from inside the lambda, and `return ret` in the outer function.

Comment: Is the value printed in the lambda function different from the one returned? Do a cout for isExist to check this. Perhaps you don't need to use [&] and instead just use []?

Comment: your `receiveCallback` lambda is probably called after `sendResultToUserCountService` returned, capturing the local stack variable `isExist` by reference ( `[&]`) will result in a dangling reference, hence you return some garbage in your lambda.

Comment: @yussuf It's more likely that the callback is called from within `handler.loop()`, in which case the reference isn't a problem, but I'm not familiar enough with RabbitMQ to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of returning a value from lambda function.
[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1GOQMqxUPM1QOqwF).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    auto greater_than_30 = [](int value) {
        return value > 30;
    };

    std::cout << "is 45 greater than 30? " << std::boolalpha
        << greater_than_30(45) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```